# XAMPP: your connection is not private NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: xampp, development-environment, test-environments, xampp-vm

I'm working in a virtual server on my 64bits windows 7 machine, and a few weeks this error start to appear on google chrome:

```
XAMPP: your connection is not private NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

I've migrated to Opera to continue developing on my virtualhost, but today this error started to appear on Opera too.

i've searched on web and only answer i've had is: 
Browsers are not accepting auto assigned certify anymore...

Anyone know how to bypass this validation on xampp virtualserver?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just an update. In Chrome and Vivaldi insert `chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost` into the address bar and then enable "Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost." Even changing the domain from `example.dev` to `example.test` didn't work until I changed the above setting in the browser.

Answer (score 7):

I could fix a similiar issue by using a different host name. I used "website.dev" an got these error in Chrome 63 on Windows7. After changing the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts to "website.test" and the "httpd-vhosts.conf" accordingly, it works.

Comment: I used website-name.dev as well and changing the domain name to .test worked. Do you know why that .dev domain name doesn't work?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to change `https://` to `http://`

Good luck, it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I had a same issue over my practicing laravel Vhost.
I changed "div" to "test" and typed "website.test" at the address bar, then it failed with the error, "ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID". But if I typed "http://website.test" instead of the one I previously did, it worked. Since then it keeps working without "http://". So I think you need to remind windows TCP/IP hosts that your new host name needs a new mapping set.

Comment: I tried it and doesn't work, but solved the problem changing my browser, now i'm using firefox, because firefox don't force "https", and i can use "http://" instead of "https://"

Answer (score 1):

I just changed the domain name from WEBSITE_NAME.dev to WEBSITE_NAME.test and it worked like a charm without me having to write "https://". Didn't had to enable insecure-host flag in chrome. It still shows "Not Secure" in the address bar, but works fine in displaying the website.

Answer (score 0):

yes,the virtual host is only worked on browser without doing this: chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost into the address bar and then enable "Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded.
Just change this:
changing the domain from example.dev to example.test.
and your virtual host gonna be work.[the result is here in the below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njt3Q.png)